# Add dynamically a gif image with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to load **programmatically** an `img` with a `.gif` extension. But the animation only happens once.

How can I add more `img` and see the animation every time I add a new `img`, not just the final state?

Note: I do not want a loop `gif`. I just want the next `img` to behave just like the first, animate then stop.

```js
var topval = 10;
var right = 10;

var addStar = function() {
 var img = $('<img id="'+topval+'">'); 
 img.attr('src','https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/musicamise/astronautAnimatedGif.gif');
 img.attr('alt','alt'+topval);
 img.css('position','absolute');
 img.css('right', right+'px');
 img.css('top', topval+'px');
 img.appendTo('body');

 topval = topval+10;
 right = right+10;
};
$("#addStar").click(addStar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
     <button id="addStar">Click do add</button>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you describe happens in Chrome and Safari, but Firefox restarts the animation each time.

Comment: How Can I make it work in Chrome and safari?  Do I need to setup smth in css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because the browser takes the same cache image. When you change the URL of the image, it's like you're looking for another image. The downside of this is that he always makes a new request for the image.

```js
var topval = 10;
var right = 10;

var count = 0;

var addStar = function(){
 var img = $('<img id="'+topval+'">'); 
 img.attr('src','https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/musicamise/astronautAnimatedGif.gif?count='+count++ );
 img.attr('alt','alt'+topval);
 img.css('position','absolute');
 img.css('right', right+'px');
 img.css('top', topval+'px');
 img.appendTo('body');

 topval = topval+10;
 right = right+10;
}
$("#addStar").click(addStar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
     <button id="addStar">Click do add</button>
</body>
```

Comment: The downside doesn't exist for me because the image is from local and not remote like the snippet! Thanks!!! that was a good working around

Answer (score 2):

You can hack around this problem by appending a random query string parameter to the URL. This tricks the browser into thinking the image is different each time. For example:

`https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/musicamise/astronautAnimatedGif.gif?x=' + Math.random()`

```js
var topval = 10;
 var right = 10;

var addStar = function(){
     var img = $('<img id="'+topval+'">'); 
     img.attr('src','https://s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/musicamise/astronautAnimatedGif.gif?x=' + Math.random());
     img.attr('alt','alt'+topval);
     img.css('position','absolute');
     img.css('right', right+'px');
     img.css('top', topval+'px');
  img.appendTo('body');

  topval = topval+10;
  right = right+10;
   }
   $("#addStar").click(addStar);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
     <button id="addStar">Click do add</button>
</body>

Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: hahahahah that's smth worth  learning!! Thankss for this hack!

Answer (score 0):

1. create a div
2. **set your gif as a background image** of your div:

   `$('myDiv').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')');`

Comment: didn't work for me, if worked for you please post a snippet. :(

Comment: Do you have access to Photoshop?
if you do, you can edit gif looping options: Go to Window > Timeline, then select looping options (bottom left corner), save as web gif and voilá

Comment: Thanks for this tip, but I really don't wanna a looped gif , thanks tho